# Problem with PayPal checkout and Braintree class

Tags: paypal, braintree

I am trying to set up a PayPal checkout with this tutorial:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#

I am facing a problem with step *6. Verify the transaction*

The php script throws:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /vendor/braintree/braintreehttp/lib/BraintreeHttp/HttpClient.php on line 38

in the Browser console.

```
function __construct(Environment $environment)
{
    $this->environment = $environment;
    $this->encoder = new Encoder();
    $this->curlCls = Curl::class;
}
```

The last line is 38. Anybody an idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and commented out line that sets curlCls

```
$this->curlCls = Curl::class;
```

It looks it is not used anywhere and the basic PayPal example started to work.